# Why are the dates not displayed correctly when using mat-date-range-input in an Angular page in an MVC .cshtml view?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using mat-date-range-input date range picker in one of my angular pages and it is displayed correctly, but when I try to use the page in my MVC .cshtml view, it is displayed as below with two dates not displayed correctly, can someone help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQO3l.png)

Using mat-date-range-input with a minimum and maximum date gives UI issues when used with asp.net mvc cshtml page.

Comment: Can you show the code for the page? Otherwise, could you maybe apply css styling to increase the height of the container?